# How to specify attribute on call of method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am having one action method.
Which is having 2 attribute

```
[Authorization]
[OutputCache]
ActionResult LoadImage()
```

I am calling LoadImage action from two method 
say 1: Index   2: Create

When i call LoadImage action from Index, I want both attribute of LoadImage to execute.
When i call LoadImage action from Create, I want only Authorization attribute to be execute.
I don't want to use VaryByParam.

Comment: Can you not simply have two different methods, each of which calls a common method to do the actual work?

Comment: then that will be redendent code. And will not be accept.

Comment: I don't believe it is possible.  ASP.NET does not perform stack-trace reflection to determine the caller.

Comment: @HemantMalpote It's not redundant if you put it in another method which both of those method call.

Answer (score 2):

Please see my earlier answer and see if that satisfy your requirement. If you really have to achieve what you stated in your question, here is how...

Define a custom Authorization attribute. Check a value coming in Request.Params to make a decision about whether to apply the attribute or skip the authorization similar to what you achieve through `AllowAnonymous` attribute.

Example code (will require some changes as per your need):

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = false)]
public sealed class ProspectProfileAuthorizationAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
   /// <summary>
   /// Special authorization check based on whether request contain valid data or not.
   /// </summary>
   /// <param name="filterContext"></param>
   public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
   {
       Guard.ArgumentNotNull(filterContext, "filterContext");
       Guard.ArgumentNotNull(filterContext.Controller, "filterContext.Controller");

       bool skipAuthorization = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.IsDefined(
           typeof(CustomAllowAnonymous), inherit: true)
                                || filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.IsDefined(
                                    typeof(CustomAllowAnonymous), inherit: true);

       if (skipAuthorization)
       {
           return;
       }

       var request = filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request;

       NameValueCollection parameterCollection = ReadQueryStringData(filterContext, request);

       if (parameterCollection.Count < 3)
       {
           throw new InvalidOperationException("Request with invalid number of parameter");
       }

       // Check 1: Is request authenticated i.e. coming from browser by a logged in user
       // No further check required.
       if (request.IsAuthenticated)
       {
           return;
       }

       // Check 2: Request is coming from an external source, is it valid i.e. does it contains
       // valid download code.
       if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(downloadCode))
       {
           throw new InvalidOperationException(Constants.Invalid_Download_Code);
       }

       if (!userType.Equals(Constants.SystemIntegrationUserName))
       {
           var exportReportService = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IExportReportService>();

           if (exportReportService != null)
           {
               if (!exportReportService.VerifyDownloadCode(downloadCode))
               {
                   // Invalid partner key
                   throw new InvalidOperationException(Constants.Invalid_Download_Code);
               }
           }
       }
   }

   private static NameValueCollection ReadQueryStringData(AuthorizationContext filterContext, HttpRequestBase request)
   {
       // Obtain query string parameter from request
       //original
       //var encryptedData = request.Params["data"];

       // Applying the replace for space with + symb
       var encryptedData = request.Params["data"].Replace(" ","+");

       var decryptedData = EncryptionHelper.DecryptString(encryptedData);

       // Validate the parameter
       var dict = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(decryptedData);

       return dict;

   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As pointed by Peter Duniho, in this situation you should have two action methods with different attribute applied to each action method as applicable.

As far as redundancy is concerned you can have common logic in a private method. This private method can be called from public action method.

I am not offering a direct solution to your problem here however I thought its important to clarify that sometimes you have to make decision to choose one principle over other. In this case I think [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) Vs [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

The suggestion here is to keep it simple and have two methods. It does not directly violate DRY anyway.

Comment: This Action is called by so many people, so i can't go and change eveybodys call to this action.

Comment: @HemantMalpote: your question says that the method is called by two others. If it's called by "so many people", how would you expect to know when not to apply the `OutputCache` attribute? If that scenario is uncommon, why not just keep the current method name as the default, and change the few (or one) place where you only want `Authorization`? (Still having both call a shared implementation, of course...named whatever you like).