# Authorize API Controller Methods Based On Route

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authorization

I'm looking for a way to conditionally enforce the `[Authorize]` attribute on API Controller methods based on the route they are accessed from.

In my software, I have pages that can be accessed one of two ways, as an authorised user with full access or as an anonymous user in "viewer mode", with limited functionality.

Both of these require access to the same API methods. I want to keep the "full" version of these calls as secure as possible, while the anonymous versions should be unimpeded. To give you an example of such a method before the "viewer mode" existed:

```
    [Route("{outerId:int}/{innerId:int}/Action")]
    public virtual HttpResponseMessage PutAction(int outerId, int innerId)
    {
        ...
    }
```

The `outerId` and `innerId` are essentially indicators of subdirectories containing the relevant data. I should also point out that the controller has the `[Authorize]` attribute.

Viewers access deep copies of this data through a different path that only requires one parameter, so my current solution is to anonymise the method and have 2 routes to differentiate the two different access types, authenticating within the method where appropriate:

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("{id:int}/{innerId:int}/Action", Order = 1)]
    [Route("{id:int}/Viewer/Action", Order = 2)]
    public virtual HttpResponseMessage PutAction(int id, int? innerId = null)
    {
        if (innerId != null) // check userId using User.Identity.GetUserId()
        ...
    }
```

This works well most of the time, but unfortunately these methods will occasionally fail when accessed by full users, as `User == null`. The `Authorize` attribute is the only thing I know that would prevent this from happening, but is there a way to only enforce this attribute for different routes?

Comment: Why don't you define a custom authorize and use it? Your implementation should check route values and take decision based on it. Let me know if you need a example.

Comment: I think I can see what you mean, if you wouldn't mind providing an example that'd be great - not quite sure which parts I would need from the tutorials etc. I've been able to find.

Comment: @SBirthare So it's not quite the same question, but I've implemented a [ViewerAuthorize] subclass, and can't for the life of me get it to trigger when I apply it to methods or classes. Is there a trick to this that isn't obvious? 

For the record, I've subclassed System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute as ViewerAuthorizeAttribute, overriden the AuthorizeCore method, and added `[ViewerAuthorize]` to a variety of classes and methods. 

I haven't been able to get breakpoints in AuthorizeCore to trigger, or have it actually work at all. Is there any obvious step that I'm missing?

Comment: Hey Dan, I implemented many custom auth attribute classes and all of them happens to override OnAuthorization. I will check what's difference but meanwhile you can try that.

Comment: I had shared my implementation to answer an older question. Not all of the code is required but you will get an idea. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27054890/how-to-specify-attribute-on-call-of-method/27055894#27055894

Comment: Hi @SBirthare, still can't get these methods to trigger or react appropriately. When you wrote these custom auth filters previously, were you able to debug them with breakpoints etc?

If you wouldn't mind going into a Stack Exchange chat, I'd be happy to show you more of the code if that would provide clarity. Of course if you're too busy, I'm very appreciative of everything you've done so far, and I can try and figure it out from here.

Comment: yes I am able to debug, something different at your end. I am curious to know and help but its bit late here in India... I will see if something is different for API controller tomorrow. By then you may be able to figure out.

Comment: Hi @SBirthare, I managed to figure it out - I was extending System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute, where apparently only System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute classes work for API controllers. Thanks for all the help! If you want to submit an answer, I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: Well I think it would be better for other users to view the solution that you used. Please add your answer. I just gave you few hints. Glad you found a solution.